# EDSDK cpp error: 10 EDS_ERR_MISSING_SUBCOMPONENT

Tags: c++, windows, windows-xp, edsdk

I am trying to get started with EDSDK to control my Canon 500D. I'm new to cpp, and windows XP apps and I'm using visual studio. After a great deal of blind trial and error I have finally managed to get the app to compile the basic sample code from the documentation. To do this I have the EDSDK.h, EDSDKTypes.h and EDSDKErrors.h headers in the right places and the EDSDK.dll and EDSDK.lib in the same folder as the code. It seems to be picking these up. I have got the 500D to be recognised by the PC so I believe the USB drivers are there.

The code is just trying to pick up the camera:

```
    EdsError err=EDS_ERR_OK;
    EdsCameraListRef cameraList=NULL;
    err = EdsGetCameraList(&cameraList);
    if(err == EDS_ERR_OK)
    {...}
```

However, when I run this console app the error is picked up as 10 - which suggests, according to the document, that there is a missing subcomponent. This happens both if the camera is connected or not, so I'm thinking this is something missing from the compile. But I am getting nowhere with the documentation.

I have installed the edsdk 2.4 Windows version from a download not the official route, so this may be an issue.

Can anyone help? Specifically how can I find out what the missing subcomponent might be so I might include it. Is this a subcmponent of the build like a header file or something like a driver?

Answer (score 0):

I know, old question but still it might help someone with the same problem.

From the documentation:

> All DLLs are required in order to execute an EDSDK client application.
>   All of the modules in the DLL folder must be copied into the same folder where the EDSDK client application is in.

This means you'll have to have all DLLs beside your *.exe. Namely these DLLs:

- DPPDLL.dll
- DPPLibCom.dll
- DPPRSC.dll
- EDSDK.dll
- EdsImage.dll
- Mlib.dll
- Ucs32P.dll